# Find a a cyclic number that start with 3 and after mutiplying it by 1.5 shift the 3 at the end of the sequence

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

I have to find a number that start with 3 and if I multiply it for 1.5 (or multiply it by 3 and divide it by 2) shift the 3 a the end of the number sequence. I guess it must be a cyclic number but I can't find it!

Answer (score 1):

Let the number be $3\cdot10^L+N$, where $N$ has $L$ digits. Then
$$\frac32(3\cdot10^L+N)=10N+3$$
$$\frac92\cdot10^L-3=\frac{17}2N$$
$$9\cdot10^L-6=17N$$
Now we check which values of $L$ satisfy $17\mid9\cdot10^L-6$, starting from $0$. The smallest such $L$ turns out to be $15$, so the smallest number satisfying the question's requirement is $3$ prepended to $\frac{9\cdot10^{15}-6}{17}$, or
$$3529411764705882$$

Comment: Thank you so much! but if i multiply 3529411764705882 by 3 and divide it by 2 the first 3 is not shifted at the end of the sequence, right?

Comment: @smfl Check for yourself. It does work.

Comment: Thanks! I've done it and the result is this, 3529411764705882 * 1,5=52941176470588200      maybe I don't undertand it right, can you please explain it to me? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @smfl Ehh... your calculator probably doesn't support big numbers like this. Use Wolfram Alpha or something like that to verify.

Comment: Right! it was my calculator!!! thank you so much for your help!!!!!!

Comment: @smfl Please upvote and accept my answer since you found it useful.